# How to get the link to the latest version of firefox addon?

Tags: html, firefox, firefox-addon, xpi

I don't want to redirect user to firefox's store to install addon. I want to user be able to install addon immediately on my own site. I know for this I should create 'a' element with href to .xpi file. But how I can get the link to the latest version of .xpi file of the addon from the firefox store?

Comment: If it is your own extension, then just host a copy on a known URL. If it is **not** your extension, then stop a moment, think a moment, then thank the Mozilla people to make that if not possible then at least hard.

Comment: it is my own extension

Comment: What do you mean "copy on a know URL"? Copy link from button "Add to firefox" on page of addon?

Comment: @EugenRieck button "Add to firefox" on page of addon in firefox store contains URL to the particular version of addon I don't want to update this link every time when new version is uploaded. I want to have link to always latest version of addon.

Comment: If it is your own extension, then just copy the .XPI to your web server where you want to link from.

Comment: @EugenRieck The same I will need to update xpi file in store and in my own server. And I will lose the statistic in store how many people download my extension

Comment: Well, you DO update your XPI when you release a new version ...

Comment: @EugenRieck How can I implement something like this: https://duckduckgo.com/app (open from Firefox and check "Add to firefox button")?

Comment: By updating your site with the new URL every time you update your extension - just as duckduckgo do it.

Comment: @EugenRieck the link of button "Add to firefox" in duckduckgo is https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/duckduckgo-for-firefox/addon-385621-latest.xpi . There is no version here it is "latest"

Comment: @EugenRieck but if you go to the store https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/duckduckgo-for-firefox/ button "Add to firefox" has harcoded latest version.

Comment: @EugenRieck I've found the solution. Please check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got it. The formula to get always the latest version of xpi file of addon:

```
addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/ADDON_NAME/addon-ADDON_ACCOUNT_ID-latest.xpi
```

- Where **ADDON_NAME** - name of addon in store. You can get it from the url of the page of addon in FF. For example for this addon https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/givero/ the ADDON_NAME is **givero**.
- Where **ADDON_ACCOUNT_ID** is id of owner account of addon. You can get it from link under the title of addon.
  [image]

  So for example for this addon https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/givero/ the link to the latest version of .xpi file will looks: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/givero/addon-14479531-latest.xpi

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Firefox Policy Templates](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md#extensionsettings), it should be possible to simply use https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/SHORT_NAME/latest.xpi, where `SHORT_NAME` corresponds to the add-on name. It does not seem to be necessary to extract the user ID (anymore?):

E.g., https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/givero/latest.xpi for [givero](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/givero/).

Answer (score 0):

Found this page while googling the error of Firefox saying it can not find the latest URL for an extension. So the problem is Firefox extension URL has weird behaviour based on individual extension URL or latest. The add-on name for individual URL will contain `_` between words and in the latest URL the add-on name will contain `-` between words.

```
https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/1234567/my_extension-1.1.0.xpi

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/my-extension/latest.xpi

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/my_extension/latest.xpi # this will not work
```